# Python speed of dividing by 10 and 2

Tags: python, performance, math, simulation, division

so i’m making a simulation (billiard) in Python that needs to do a lot of updates per second. I know that division (or multiplying by decimal) is one of the slower operations. I was just wondering if that only goes for more “abstract” divisions (ex: ‘173/82’) or if it also goes for “easier” divisions, halving float or dividing by 10.

For extra info, it is for microstepping (getting a more accurate point of collision) so I’ll be dividing the speed. If it is costly to divide by 2 and 10, I’m thinking about precalculating the smaller speeds (on change of the balls speed), but please do suggest if there might be a better way.
Thanks for reading:)

Comment: Note that for binary floating point, division by 10 is not particularly easier than by any other divisor.  Division by 2 potentially is simpler, but at the Python level you're *way* above those details.

Comment: Before worrying about the costs of arithmetic operations, you really ought to *test* to see whether there's anything to worry about.  Estimate what mixture and rate of arithmetic operations you need, and see whether Python runing on your target machine can comfortably do that.  Or even write the whole program first, and only if necessary go back and make the slowest parts faster.

Comment: One possibility (which you might consider radical) is to use a completely different simulation paradigm -- discrete event simulation.  People coming from the physics world are used to thinking in terms of time-stepped models, but movement, sensing, and and collisions can all be handled very efficiently by DES as described [here](https://informs-sim.org/wsc05papers/118.pdf).

Comment: The key insight is to conceptualize the state of billiard balls as (start_location, start_time, velocity) rather than (current_location, velocity). That means the current position can be queried at any point in time, but the state only needs to be updated when a collision event with a wall, another ball, or a pocket occurs, all of which can easily be projected and scheduled to occur when they actually occur rather than updating the location of every ball on every delta-t time tick. That’s also [more accurate](https://www.informs-sim.org/wsc10papers/135.pdf) than time-stepped models.

Comment: @pjs Yes, that was my thought too. I looked into it for a few hours here today, but I’m not able to get it to work when considering friction of the table (velocity is multiplied by 0.99 after each update). I’m not too far into mathematics in school and such, so had trouble with making it a function that would work when considering previous velocity changes and position changes.

Answer (score 5):

Python is a very high level language which abstracts away floating point numbers as full objects. This kind of micro-optimization does not make sense in plain Python code.

If you are down to the algorithm you have to optimize in a few plain operations, one of the steps you could take is to promote the function where the calculation is to  a helper framework that will run that code in native code, such as [cython](https://cython.org/) or [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/). Cython, for example, will feature the same syntax as Python and be callable from ordinary Python code, but will be able to use the native CPU floating point implementation for the operations. Numba may be even simpler, requiring simply that the most critical functions be properly decorated.

If the results are to be consumed from and go into an array, you won't even have the language overhead of converting the value to a Python float instance or each data point.

Comment: I would strongly recommend having a go with `numba` rather than `cython`, it's much easier to get started with I.M.H.O. Might be enough to add just a `@numba.jit` on the simulation function.

Comment: (numba reference added in new edit - feel free to improve the text)

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to try it, just write a few lines of test code and loop over it a few million times.  That's the beauty of Python, you can try things quickly.

Under the covers, the Python interpreter is doing a lot of work and the actual division itself will likely be a small component of the time.

Once the algorithm is right, you might try writing custom functions or classes for Python, in C.  I've done this for Monte-Carlo simulation that has to handle millions of events per second.